# Running intel mkl sample program - No such file

Tags: c++, intel-mkl

I am trying to run a sample file from Intel on using its mkl software with C++.  However, I am unable to get it to run.  As I have never used C++, I assume I am making a simple error.

[Here](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/mkl_sa/11/tutorials/mkl_mmx_c/tutorial_mkl_mmx_c.pdf) is the Intel document instructions I followed along with the sample code.  It starts on page 11.

I am running this in my terminal:

```
g++ -m64 -I/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.5.198/mkl/include dgemm_example.c
```

And this is my error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_MKL_free", referenced from:
      _main in cc9RJYcW.o
  "_MKL_malloc", referenced from:
      _main in cc9RJYcW.o
  "_cblas_dgemm", referenced from:
      _main in cc9RJYcW.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I should note I am running this on my mid-2012 macbook retina.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you did not add MKL libraries

Try add

```
-L/path/to/MKL/libguide.so -L...
```

This website might help you more or less

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor